# Is IIS 7.5 required for ASP.NET MVC 5.1, ASP.NET Web API 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

After upgrading the project to WebApi 2.1 and MVC 5.1 getting following errors on IIS7:

> ***This operation requires IIS version 7.5 or higher running in integrated pipeline mode.***
>
> **Description:**  An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:**  System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS version 7.5 or higher running in integrated
>   pipeline mode.
>
> **Source Error:**  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:** 
>   [PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS version
>   7.5 or higher running in integrated pipeline mode.]    System.Web.HttpResponse.get_ClientDisconnectedToken() +3127102
>   System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.get_ClientDisconnectedToken() +9
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpResponseBaseExtensions.GetClientDisconnectedTokenWhenFixed(HttpResponseBase
>   response) +58
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.d__0.MoveNext() +134 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) +60
>   System.Web.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +6
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9514812    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
>
> __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____ Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.18408

Comment: Short answer, **Yes**.
Long answer, **Yes**.
Feel free to modify your question in order to obtain a more detailed answer.

Comment: Did you see such requirement documented somewhere? I couldn't find such requirements anywhere. And we were already using WebApi 2, which worked fine on IIS7

Comment: you were using WebAPI2, not 2.1, under IIS 7, right?

Comment: From what I understand and from what I've been told by the Microsoft rep here at my company, IIS 7.5 is required for WebAPI version 2.1.

Comment: Correct WebAPI2 worked well on II7 before upgrade to WebAPI2.1

Comment: Just FYI...we currently have a  bug logged for this

Comment: Kiran works for Microsoft.

Comment: @KiranChalla, great news! Is there a public issue tracking system to track updates of this issue?

Comment: Its here : http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1645

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a regression from Web API 2 to 2.1. Following bug is keeping tracking of this:

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1645

**NOTE**:
The fix has been released today (2/10/2014). Make sure to update your packages.

Comment: Folks, this issue has been fixed and new updated packages have been posted to nuget.org. Please update your packages.

Answer (score 5):

We had this issue and resolved by following settings in VS 2012

> Right Click Web Role-> Properties - > Web ->  Servers -> Select Use
>   Local IIS Web Server.